# Restricting user access on sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

i have a rails app with sorcery
everything work .
the problem is when edit a user like :
    http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit
its work fine , but when i change the user id to 2 or 3 ..
i can update all users data
how can i restrict the edit page only if the current user is the one that logged in

here is my controller :

```
skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create, :show]

def new
 @user = User.new
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  auto_login(@user)
  flash[:info] = "Welcome."
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
end

def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do something like this

```
before_action :edit_rights?, only: [:update, :edit]

private
def edit_rights?
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user == @user
end
```

you won't need `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in both `update` and `edit` actions then

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to do that. First and straightforward is detailed in another answer, fine-tune your controller.

A less obvious way is to create a singular resource and its own controller. In routes that could look like:

```
resource :profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
# generates:
# /profile (GET, PATCH, PUT)
# /profile/edit (GET)
```

Then create a controller that is responible solely for user's own profile and operates only on `current_user`.

Yes, it's okay for one model to have multiple controllers, if your model should behave really differently in different parts of your app.

#### Why would you do that?

- User's own profile could show much more information than is available publicly, you can lay it out in a separate view
- No "access denied" errors, as the resource is auto-selected via `current_user`, all you need is ensure the user is logged in in the entire controller.